# Check the email input validate the business email only (eg:yourname@firmname.com) not accept the other public provides

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to not accept @gmail @yahoo @bing @yopmail @aol @any_other_public_providers ,,I want to accept valid company emails

If you want to ensure that the email address doesn't have the domain "gmail.com,"

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#customer_email').on('input', function() {
        // Get the entered email value
        var email = $(this).val();

        // Regular expression for a business email format (excluding gmail.com)
        var businessEmailRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@(?!gmail\.com)[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/;

        // Check if the entered email matches the business email format
        if (businessEmailRegex.test(email)) {
            // Valid business email format
            $('.email-invalid-validation-msg').addClass('d-none');
        } else {
            // Invalid business email format
            $('.email-invalid-validation-msg').removeClass('d-none');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be vastly simplified, but not exhaustive.

Note I use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to get the word just after the @

```js
const invalidEmailDomains = ["gmail", "aol"]
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#customer_email').on('input', function() {
    // Get the entered email value
    let email = $(this).val();
    let domain = email.match(/@(\w+)\./)?.[1];
    console.log(domain)
    $('.email-invalid-validation-msg').toggle(invalidEmailDomains.includes(domain))
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="customer_email" type="email">
<span class="email-invalid-validation-msg">Invalid email</span>
```